# C++ - (zero cost?) proxy like operator=(value) -> std::map[key]=value inside class

Tags: c++

What is better way to create a (zero cost?) proxy like `operator=(value)` -> `map[key]=value`?

For now I use something like that, but it's not zero cost and certainly not the best option.

And yes, target map will live guaranteed all the time that proxy lives.

```
template <int key>
class proxy {
public:
    std::map<int,int> & proxy_m;

    proxy(std::map<int,int> & m) : proxy_m(m) {}

    void operator=(int value) {
        proxy_m[key] = value;
    }
};

class A {
public:
    std::map<int,int> m;

    proxy<1> proxy_one {m};
};

...

A a;
a.proxy_one = 1; // a.m[1] = 1;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "zero cost"?

Comment: Hm, I'm surprised it's not (execution time) zero-cost after compiler optimization. I see how it's not memory-neutral (need to allocate memory for proxy object). Furthermore, I don't really see why your proxy class is more convenient than adding methods to your `A`.

Comment: If you have just one predefined key then use an `int` field instead of map.

Comment: Why not just implement support for `a.set<1>(1)` or the equally good `a.set(1, 1)`?

Comment: By zero-cost I mean no additional memory allocations and as-minimun-as-possible time overhead.

I have not just one key, so no, I can't do that.

Yeah, I can do this by methods, and thanks for idea with set, but instead of 1 I have a bunch of consts inside a namespace, and it's inside some namespaces, so for user it's will be simplier to write a.proxy_one instead of a.set<my::namespace::proxy_one>. And yes, I know, it's not so critical, I'm just curious. )

Comment: So you mean no cost on top of the cost of calling something like `some_map[key] = value;`?

Comment: What is *non*-zero about your current implementation?

Comment: I'm not very good with complier optimiation algorithms, but I think that allocation of map reference weights some bytes.

Yes, I mean "costs exactly as map::operator[]".

Comment: You need to be more specific about your criteria.  The obvious answer is "just type `some_map[1]=value`"; that has the runtime behaviour you want.  What, **exactly** and **as liberally as possible** do you **need** from this proxy system on top of direct access?  Because unless you state those unstated requirements, we get "must be exactly like what I wrote" which doesn't leave room for improvement or innovation  We don't know what part of your proxy plan can be discarded, and what parts are important.  "better" is vague.

Comment: Oh, sorry. This criteria is not strict, I'm simply wonderng if there is some methods to achive that behaviour (like in two last lines in my example) without additional memory allocation, or with some improvements that rises efficiency to the same level as `some_map[1]=value` do, or almost. The map is in private, and there is already a common setter, and it's not that critical to write long names (or to use `using` statement). And yes, I understood already that simple setter method like `a.proxy_one(value)` will be great, so I just curious about that case, maybe I can use it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the non-zero-cost you mention is that your proxy<1> stores a reference to the map, and therefore forces the creation of redundant storage which the compiler cannot optimise away.

I think the solution for you is to take a reference to the map at the point of use, so the compiler can use 'as if' optimisations to remove it.

For example:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>

template <int key>
class proxy {
public:
    std::map<int,int> & proxy_m;

    proxy(std::map<int,int> & m) : proxy_m(m) {}

    void operator=(int value) {
        proxy_m[key] = value;
    }
};

template<int N>
using key = std::integral_constant<int, N>;

class A {
public:
    std::map<int,int> m;

    template<int N>
    auto get_proxy(key<N>) {
        return proxy<1>(m);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    // in reality no proxy<> will be created and no reference taken
    // provided you enable optimisations.
    a.get_proxy(key<1>()) = 1; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Interesting approach, thanks for the idea.